# Mailchimp 3.0 PHP Add Subscriber Directly To List Without An Opt-In

Tags: php, mailchimp

My question is about using the Mailchimp 3.0 API and PHP to add a subscriber directly to my mailing list.

The code I'm using (see below) functions as expected and adds the subscriber. However, the subscriber is sent an opt-in email.

[screenshot of test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ez3Y.jpg)

The code is from here: http://www.johnkieken.com/mailchimp-form-using-api-v3-0-and-jquery-ajax/

The desired behavior is to add the subscriber directly to the list without the opt-in email, as well as provide a message on the site they have been successfully subscribed.

My server is running PHP 5.3.16.

I have the HTML file, the Mailchimp API wrapper (mailchimp.php) and subscribe.php all residing in the same directory for testing purposes.

I'm not well versed in coding, so I hope someone can help.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="signup" action="index.html" method="get">
    First Name: <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" />
    Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" />
    email Address (required): <input type="email" name="email" id="email" />
    <input type="submit" id="SendButton" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<div id="message"></div>

<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#signup').submit(function() {
        $("#message").html("Adding your email address...");
        $.ajax({
            url: 'subscribe.php', // proper url to your "store-address.php" file
            type: 'POST', // <- IMPORTANT
            data: $('#signup').serialize() + '&ajax=true',
            success: function(msg) {
                var message = $.parseJSON(msg),
                    result = '';
                if (message.status === 'pending') { // success
                    result = 'Success!  Please click the confirmation link that will be emailed to you shortly.';
                } else { // error
                    result = 'Error: ' + message.detail;
                }
                $('#message').html(result); // display the message
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**subscribe.php**

```
<?php // for MailChimp API v3.0

include('MailChimp.php');  // path to API wrapper downloaded from GitHub

use \DrewM\MailChimp\MailChimp;

function storeAddress() {

    $key        = "mymailchimpAPIkey-us17";
    $list_id    = "mymailchimplistid";

    $merge_vars = array(
        'FNAME'     => $_POST['fname'],
        'LNAME'     => $_POST['lname']
    );

    $mc = new MailChimp($key);

    // add the email to your list
    $result = $mc->post('/lists/'.$list_id.'/members', array(
            'email_address' => $_POST['email'],
            'merge_fields'  => $merge_vars,
            'status'        => 'pending'     // double opt-in
            // 'status'     => 'subscribed'  // single opt-in
        )
    );

    return json_encode($result);

}

// If being called via ajax, run the function, else fail

if ($_POST['ajax']) { 
    echo storeAddress(); // send the response back through Ajax
} else {
    echo 'Method not allowed - please ensure JavaScript is enabled in this browser';
}
```

If I edit subscribe.php to:

```
// add the email to your list
$result = $mc->post('/lists/'.$list_id.'/members', array(
        'email_address' => $_POST['email'],
        'merge_fields'  => $merge_vars,
        //'status'        => 'pending'     // double opt-in
        'status'     => 'subscribed'  // single opt-in
    )
);
```

I get the following message:

"Error: email@domain.com is already a list member. Use PUT to insert or update list members."

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the subscriber that you are trying to `POST` is already a list member (likely in a *pending* state). Perhaps from an earlier `POST` where `'status' => 'pending'`. In these cases you would need to make a `PUT` or `PATCH` request in order to update the contact that is already in MailChimp. This is because `POST` requests are for adding a new record only. Documentation for a `PUT` request to the list members endpoint can be found here:

http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/members/#edit-put_lists_list_id_members_subscriber_hash

It looks like you are using `drewm/mailchimp-api`. I'm not super familiar with this library but it looks like you can just call `$mc->patch(...)` or `$mc->put(...)`.

If you make `PUT` requests then MailChimp will update a record for an email address if it already exists and will create it if it does not. So it sounds like you should just stick to `PUT` requests for the desired behavior you described above.